# JSON Output in Test is Not Including Sub Class Fields

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, httpresponse

I have an abstract class called ContentProviderBean and then a java bean that extends the abstract class (for simplicity call it ExtendsContentProviderBean) to include additional fields.

I want to produce a Json response that contains the parent as well as the child's extra fields.  So I've made an ObjectResponse, which should do this as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ObjectResponse {

    @XmlElement
    private String result;
    @XmlElement
    private ContentProviderBean object;

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public void setObject(ContentProviderBean object) {

        System.err.println("ContentProviderBean::: " + object);

        this.object = object;
    }

}
```

**The System.err line in setObject is successfully showing all fields of the sub class ContentProviderBean** (ExtendContentProviderBean), but the Json response only includes the fields of the parent (ContentProviderBean).

**The following code is part of the testing code that I'm using, which runs the above code that is in production.**  It uses the tiny java server tjws, and ClientRequest and ClientResponse (org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest).

```
@Test
public void testObjectEndpoint() throws Exception{

    final String contentEndpoint = ENDPOINT + "/object/{guid}";

    logger.info("testing endpoint: " + contentEndpoint);

    ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(contentEndpoint);

    request     .pathParameter("guid", "SOMEGUID_25")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    ClientResponse<String> response = request.get(String.class);

    System.err.println(response.getEntity());

    logger.info("Response Entity:: JSON: " + response.getEntity());

}
```

**The real implementation uses Jackson, and successfully returns the correct Json object.**
That is, it includes the parent fields, as well as the fields in ExtendsContentProviderBean.

So why is the test case not returning the correct JSon object as the real implementation, which uses Jackson?

EDIT:  I was asked to show example Json.

Here is sample Json from the testObjectEndpoint() method

```
{
   "result":"success",
   "object":{
      "creationDate":"2013-09-10T16:08:00-04:00",
      "defaultImg":"http:\/\/someurl2",
      "objectId":25,
      "securityDescriptor":"sec desc 2",
      "title":"title 2",
      "userId":"user id 22"
   }
}
```

Here is the Json that the Jackson provider returns:

```
{
   "result":"success",
   "object":{
      "objectId":"25",
      "userId":"user id 22",
      "creationDate":1378843680000,
      "securityDescriptor":"sec desc 2",
      "title":"title 2",
      "defaultImg":"http://someurl2",
      "contentType":"CONTENT",
      "size":3,
      "lastEditDate":1378843680000
   }
}
```

**Note that the last two fields in the Jackson return Json are from the child class.**

Comment: Can you show us a sample JSON?

Comment: Updated per your comment.